# How to Delete a CRM Attribute that is referenced by Business Rule

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-online

I'm attempting to delete an Attribute from an Entity in CRM online 2015 Sp1 that is referenced in a Business Rule.  I am running the `RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest` to get the workflows that reference the field, then I'm updating the name of the field in the XAML to be a different field, first dis-activating the workflow, then updating the workflow, the activating it.  No matter what I do, I can't seem to remove the dependency of this field in the Workflow/Business Rule.

This is what my current logic is doing:

```cs
private void UpdateWorkflows(IOrganizationService service, AttributeMetadata from, AttributeMetadata to)
{
    Trace("Checking for Workflow Dependencies");
    var depends = ((RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteResponse)service.Execute(new RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest
    {
        ComponentType = (int)componenttype.Attribute,
        ObjectId = from.MetadataId.GetValueOrDefault()
    })).EntityCollection.ToEntityList<Dependency>().Where(d => d.DependentComponentTypeEnum == componenttype.Workflow).ToList();

    if (!depends.Any())
    {
        Trace("No Workflow Dependencies Found");
        return;
    }

    foreach (var workflow in service.GetEntitiesById<Workflow>(depends.Select(d => d.DependentComponentObjectId.GetValueOrDefault())))
    {
        Trace("Updating {0} - {1} ({2})", workflow.CategoryEnum.ToString(), workflow.Name, workflow.Id);
        workflow.Xaml = workflow.Xaml.Replace("\"" + from.LogicalName + "\"", "\"" + to.LogicalName + "\"");
        var activate = workflow.StateCode.Value == WorkflowState.Activated;
        if (activate)
        {
            service.Execute(new SetStateRequest()
            {
                EntityMoniker = workflow.ToEntityReference(),
                State = new OptionSetValue((int) WorkflowState.Draft),
                Status = new OptionSetValue((int) workflow_statuscode.Draft)
            });
        }
        service.Update(workflow);
        if (activate)
        {
            service.Execute(new SetStateRequest()
            {
                EntityMoniker = workflow.ToEntityReference(),
                State = new OptionSetValue((int)WorkflowState.Activated),
                Status = new OptionSetValue((int)workflow_statuscode.Activated)
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are there still waiting workflow instances present in the system?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen it's a Business Rule.  Not sure that's even possible.  If I manually update the field via the UI, it works correctly...

Comment: So, when I understand you well, you can delete the field when you perform all required actions through the user interface, but you cannot do the same programmatically?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen yes, If I update the Business Rule via the UI, it allows the deletion of the attribute.  Updating the Workflow for the Business Rule does not remove the dependency on the field.  Added Current Logic

Comment: Are you sure your code actually selected the desired workflow definitions? If yes, what happens when you deactivate and reactivate the updated workflows through the UI after your program has run?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen I'm sure, the RetrieveDependenciesForDeleteRequest still returns the same workflow.  I haven't tried that, but I don't have the system in a state to test that currently...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally Figured this one out!  There are Process Triggers that also get created with Business Rules:

Added this extra step and everything is working now!

```
var triggers = service.GetEntities<ProcessTrigger>(ProcessTrigger.Fields.ProcessId, workflow.Id, 
                                                   ProcessTrigger.Fields.ControlName, from.LogicalName);
if (triggers.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (var trigger in triggers)
    {
        Trace("Updating Trigger {0} for Workflow", trigger.Id);
        service.Update(new ProcessTrigger
        {
            Id = trigger.Id,
            ControlName = to.LogicalName
        });
    }
}
```